# What is the purpose of -m, --match in an Iptables rule?

Tags: iptables

Many Iptables rules contain this `-m` or `--match` option, for example

```
-I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 30/minute --limit-burst 5 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP
```

Is this `-m` or `--match` simply  "special" option which is a precursor to an "normal" option?
for example, with this rule

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
```

Does the term `-m tcp` say to Iptables, *the next option that follows will be intended for the `tcp` module* - then  the `--tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN` term will be interpreted in that context?
To put it another way, would the option `-m tcp` be meaningless if it was specified by itself inside an Iptables rule?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-m` or `--match` option is used to enable one or more *extended packet matching modules* with the given name(s). Take for example the module `connbytes`. This can be used to create rules that match how many bytes a connection has transferred.

The man page for `iptables` gives a good description of this:

> iptables can use extended packet matching modules. These are loaded in
>   two ways: implicitly, when -p or --protocol is specified, or with the
>   -m or --match options, followed by the matching module name; after these, various extra command line options become available, depending
>   on the specific module. You can specify multiple extended match
>   modules in one line, and you can use the -h or --help options after
>   the module has been specified to receive help specific to that module.

I would highly recommend reading through the `iptables-extensions` man page, which documents the modules included in the standard distribution of iptables:

```
$ man iptables-extensions
```

Comment: thanks, so in terms of usage when you are specifying rules,  my assumptions were basically correct?

Comment: I would say so. Concerning the query you posed at the end of your question, the `-m tcp` option enables the tcp extended packet matching module, which itself provides the `--tcp-flags` option. So yes `-m tcp` may be meaningless if none of the extensions provided by the module are used.

Comment: if `man iptables-extensions` not available, look in `man iptables` and search for `EXTENSIONS`